# Cosa vuol dire "trovata" in questo contesto?

Tags: word-meaning

Nel romanzo *Ferito a morte*, di Raffaele La Capria, ho letto (grassetto mio):

> Ninì a Capri naturalmente. Dice che senza **trovate** Capri è morta, e chi ha una **trovata** là viene considerato un dio, fa pubblicità all’isola e incrementa il turismo.

Ho letto tutte le accezioni di "trovata" che si trovano sul [vocabolario Treccani](https://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/trovata) e sul [*Grande dizionario della lingua italiana*](http://www.gdli.it/JPG/GDLI21/00000426.jpg), ma non riesco a vedere a quale possa corrispondere l'uso che se ne fa nel testo. Cosa sarebbero queste "trovate" a cui si riferisce Ninì?

Comment: Nel Treccani a proposito di "trovata" dice: "più genericam., idea felice: è una bella t., un’ottima t., una vera t.;". Quindi in questo caso trovata = idea.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Una “[trovata](https://dizionari.repubblica.it/Italiano/T/trovata.html)“ è un’idea originale, spesso qualcosa a cui nessuno aveva pensato.

Nel contesto si riferisce ad un’idea che possa attirare  turisti sull’isola.